# Почему вход через Яндекс почту стсал недоступен?

Tags: поддержка

Почему сейчас невозможно войти через Яндекс почту? На сайте произошли какие-то изменения? Раньше я заходил именно через нее. Сегодня попытался войти - не смог.
Пишет: 400 Неизвестно приложение с таким client_id